# Conflict between the color in a:link and .nav-link

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I use the bootstrap css and the css style sheet by myself. For the following part,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">  
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want "Home, About, Contact" to be black rather than darkred as my other links. So in my css file, I write

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
color:darkred;
}
.nav-link {
  color: black;
}
```

But they turn out to still be darkred. How do I fix this conflict?

Comment: Have a read up on specificity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: The colon following the selector is a typo and causes that selector to be discarded.

Comment: OK. I fixed the typo. To my understanding, a:link is a class and nav-link is also a class. So for "Home, About, Contact", both of them have the same specificity value and somehow a:link wins?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing to

```
.navbar .nav-link {
  color: black;
}
```